# Migrating from monolith to microservices reusing data layer

Tags: domain-driven-design, orm, microservices, persistence

We are basically in process of moving from monolith system to microservices and we avoided migrating monolith system all at once, or as they call it a "big bang"

https://www.nginx.com/blog/refactoring-a-monolith-into-microservices/

Since our microservices are built using DDD, where domain is persistence ignorant, we are considering a different approach for extracting a part of monolith to this new microservice.

We would like to know what would the downside be of adding a new domain (microservice) on top of existing data "layer"?

Adding a domain would help us achieve much wanted centralized business logic and since orms promote persistence ignorance, we could theoretically reuse the existing data "layer" (database), with possible modifications.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Do you mean to have a microservice wrapping your database and then all microservices you extract from the monolith to connect to the database using this microservice? If that is it, then note that microservices don't share databases, they each have their own.

Comment: No, I mean extract the part of database needed for new microservice to a new database, build new domain and map new domain with new db with minimum adjustment to make microservics fully functional

Comment: Do you want to split the data layer of the monolith and use one part per microservice?